# iostat: what is exactly the concept of merge

Tags: io, iostat

From `iostat` man pages:

```
rrqm/s
 The number of read requests merged per second that were queued to the device.

wrqm/s
 The number of write requests merged per second that were queued to the device.

r/s
  The number (after merges) of read requests completed per second for the device.

w/s
  The number (after merges) of write requests completed per second for the device.
```

Can anyone elaborate on the `merge` concept since the documentation does not provide any further details?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A merge happens when two i/o requests can be collapsed into one single longer-length request. For example, a write to block 1234 followed by a write to block 1235 can be merged into a single i/o request for block 1234 of length 2 blocks. As this sort of situation can be fairly common it is worth putting the effort in the kernel to do the merge, freeing up an i/o request structture, and reducing interrupt overhead.

If you are interested in more detailed statistics on this aspect of i/o see the pdf [btt user guide](http://www.fis.unipr.it/doc/blktrace-1.0.1/btt.pdf) which is part of `blktrace`.